# Getting an XML node and storing it in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have an XML response and I need to get just a certain part (node?) of that response.

This is the response but I need to store ... in a variable so I can use it in another function:

```
<GetUserCollectionFromSite xmlns=
   "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/">
   <Users>
      <User ID="4" Sid="S-1-5-21-2127521184-1604012920-1887927527-
         34577" Name="User1_Display_Name" 
         LoginName="DOMAIN\User1_Alias" Email="User1_E-mail" 
         Notes="Notes" IsSiteAdmin="False" IsDomainGroup="False" />
      <User ID="5" Sid="S-1-5-21-2127521184-1604012920-1887927527-
         354403" Name="User2_Display_Name" 
         LoginName="DOMAIN\User2_Alias" Email="User2_E-mail" 
         Notes="Notes" IsSiteAdmin="False" IsDomainGroup="False" />
         .
         .
         .
   </Users>
</GetUserCollectionFromSite>
```

I tried this: `allUserXML = $(xData.responseXML).find('Users');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: $(response).find("Users").text();